# Original intent bundle retained upon screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-intent, orientation-changes, android-savedstate, onsaveinstancestate

Is the original info passed to an activity at creation (e.g. an `Intent` `Bundle` from `getIntent().getExtras()`) retained when the screen orientation is changed?  Can I just call `getIntent().getExtras()` again after rotation to obtain the info again?  Or do I need to save that info myself in `onSaveInstanceState` and retrieve it from the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the original info passed to an activity at creation (e.g. an Intent
>   Bundle from getIntent().getExtras()) retained when the screen
>   orientation is changed?

Yes it is retained. It's also retained for other configuration changes (like keyboard shown, screen size change etc..)

> Can I just call getIntent().getExtras() again after rotation to obtain
>   the info again?

Yes you can.

> Or do I need to save that info myself in onSaveInstanceState and
>   retrieve it from the savedInstanceState Bundle?

No need to save it manually.